# How to determine MCU Clock speed requirements

Tags: arm, embedded, microcontroller

**Overview:**

I spent a while trying to think of how to formulate this question. To narrow the scope, I wanted to provide my initial HW requirements in the form of a ‘real life’ example application.

I understand that clock speed is probably relative, in the sense that it is a case by case basis. For example, your requirement for a certain speed may be impacted on by the on-chip peripherals offered by the MCU. As an example, you may spend (n) cycles servicing an ISR for an encoder, or, you could pick an MCU that has a QEI input to do it for you (to some degree), which in turn, may loosen your requirement?

I am not an expert, and am very much still learning, so please call me out if I use an incorrect term, or completely misinterpret something. I assure you; the feedback is welcome!

---

**Example Application:**

This application is relatively simple. It can be thought of as a non-blocking state machine, where each ‘iteration’ of the machine must complete within 20ms. A single iteration of this machine has 4 main tasks:

1. Decode a serial payload, consisting of 32 bytes. The length is fixed at 32 bytes, payload is dynamic, baud is 115200bps (See Task #2 below)
2. Read 4 incremental shaft encoder signals, which are coupled with 4 DC Motors, 1 encoder for each motor (See Task #1 Below)
3. Determine the position of 4 limit switches. ISR driven, trigger on rising edge for each switch.
4. Based on the 3 categories of inputs above, the MCU will output 4 separate PWM signals @ 50Hz (20ms) to a motor controller for its next set of movements. (See Task #3 below)

From an IO perspective, I know that the MCU is on the hook for reading 8 digital signals (4 quadrature encoders, 4 limit switches), and decoding a serial frame of 32 bytes over UART.

Based on that data, the MCU will output 4 independent PWM signals, with a pulse width of [1000usec -3200usec], per motor, to the motor controller.

---

**The Question:**

After all is said and done, I am trying to think through how I can map my requirements into MCU selection, solely from a speed point of view.

It’s easy for me to look through the datasheet and say, this chip meets my requirements because it has (n) UARTS, (n) ISR input pins, (n) PWM outputs etc. But my projects are so small that I always assume the processor is ‘fast enough’. Aside from my immediate peripheral needs, I never really look into the actual MCU speed, which is an issue on my end.

To resolve that, I am trying to understand what goes into selecting a particular clock speed, based on the needs of a given application. Or, another way to say it, which is probably wrong, but how to you quantify the theoretical load on the processor for that specific application?

---

*Additional Information*

---

**Task #1: Encoder:**

Each of the 4 motors have different tasks within the system, but regardless, they are the same brand/model motor, and have a maximum RPM of 230. My assumption is, if at its worst case, one of the motors is spinning at 230 RPM, that would mean, at full quadrature resolution (count rising/falling for channel A/B) the 1000PPR encoder would generate 4K interrupts per revolution. As such, the MCU would have to service those interrupts, potentially creating a bottleneck for the system. For example, if (n) number of clock cycles are required to service the ISR, and for 1 revolution of 1 motor, we expect 4K interrupts, that would be … 230(RPM) * 4K (ISR per rev) == 920,000 interrupts per minute? Yikes! And then I guess you could just extrapolate and say, again, at it’s worst case, where each of the 4 motors are spinning at 230 RPM, there’s a potential that, if the encoders are full resolution, the system would have to endure 920K interrupts per minute for each encoder. So 920K * 4 motors == 3,680,000 interrupts per minute? I am 100% sure I am doing something wrong, so please, feel free to set me straight.

**Task #2: Serial Decoding**

The MCU will require a dedicated HW serial port to decode a packet of 32 bytes, which repeats, with different values, every 7ms. Baud rate will be set to 115200bps.

**Task #3: PWM Output**

Based on the information from tasks 1 and 2, the MCU will write to 4 separate PWM outputs. The pulse for each output will be between 1000-3200usec with a frequency of 50Hz.

Comment: Gonna break it down slightly differently - assume 4 RPSecond x 4 states (A/B/Rise/Fall) = 16 states per second.  I think you actually multipled by 4 twice - once to get to 1000PPR and again when you went to 4K.  Assuming my 16 states per second, we then multiply by 4 for 4 motors to get 64 motor * states / second.  This is roughly as fast as a VBlank and is not bad overhead at all.  Multiply by the amount of time required to encode the data in cycles, add some overhead for the ISR, and this is not heavy.  Take with a grain of salt as I am not an expert here, but your math looks funny.

Comment: I guess I'd do a full dimensional analysis of your conversion figures to make sure that final result makes sense.

Comment: Both A and B dont change per pulse yes?  Essentially one changes per state?  4 states 1000PPR so 250 state changes per revolution?  230 rpm so  57500 "interrupts" per minute or 958 per second per motor, four motors so 3833 per second.

Comment: 16MHz for example, that is about 4000 clocks per handler in an ideal world, that could be 100 instructions up to a few thousand.  But there are other issues, you have four of them changing at once, what is the response rate to change the pwm, what does your algorithm look like, has to be fixed point imo, not float unless you get one with an FPU.

Comment: then serial is its own deal and does the uart have a fifo how does it handle if you let it get too far behind, etc. mcus dont run the whole chip at one clock rate necessarily so you can get 200+MHz mcus but the peripherals run at a fraction sometimes so that slows down the cpu waiting on that peripheral.  etc etc...you might want to use a cpld for the motor control instead of an mcu...you might want to have one mcu per motor then a central one to talk to the four and the central one can handle the uart...

Comment: mcu eval boards are super cheap you can take a stab at the control algorithm, fake the input and see how long it takes to execute the math to handle one state change in the rotation.  Then add an overhead factor to cover code changes, talking to the interrupt handler, the perpheral, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to separate real-time critical parts from the rest of the application. For example, the actual reception of an UART frame is somewhat time-critical if you do so interrupt-based. But the protocol decoding is not critical at all unless you are expected to respond within a certain time.

> Decode a serial payload, consisting of 32 bytes.

You can either do this the old school way with interrupts filling up a buffer, or you could look for a part with DMA, which is fairly common nowadays. DMA means that you won't have to consider some annoying, relatively low frequency UART interrupt disrupting other tasks.

> Read 4 incremental shaft encoder signals

I haven't worked with such encoders so I can't tell how time-critical they are. If you have to catch every single interrupt and your calculations are correct, then 3,680,000 interrupts per minute is still not that bad. 60*60/3680000 = 978us. So roughly one interrupt every millisecond, that's not a "hard real-time" requirement. If that's the only time-critical thing you need to do, then any shabby 8-bitter running at 8MHz could keep up.

> Determine the position of 4 limit switches

You don't mention timing here but I assume this is something that could be polled cyclically by a low priority cyclic timer.

> the MCU will output 4 separate PWM signals

Not a problem, just pick one with a decent PWM hardware peripheral. You should just need to update some PWM duty cycle registers now and then.

---

Overall, this doesn't sound all that real-time critical. I've done much worse real-time projects with icky 8 and 16 bitters. However, each time I did, I always regret not picking a faster MCU, because you always come up with stuff to add as the project/product goes on.

It sounds like your average mainstream Cortex M0+ would be a good candidate for this project. Clock it at ~48MHz and you'll have plenty of CPU power. Cortex M4 or larger if you actually expect floating point math (I don't quite see why you'd need that though).

Given the current component crisis, be careful with which brand you pick though! In particular stay clear of STM32, since ST can't produce them right now and you might end up waiting over a year until you get parts.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the question is "experience".  But intuitively your example is not particularly taxing - although there are plenty of ways you could mess it up.  I once worked on a project that ran on a 200MHz C5502 DSP at near 100% CPU load.  The application now runs on a 72MHz Cortex-M3 at only 60% with additional functionality and I/O not present in the original implementation..

Your application is I/O bound; depending on data rates (and critically interrupt rates), I/O seldom constitutes the highest CPU load, and DMA, hardware FIFOs, input capture timer/counters, and hardware PWM etc. can be used to minimise the I/O impact.  I shan't go into it in detail; @Lundin has already done that.

Note also that raw processor speed is important for data or signal processing and number crunching - but what I/O generally requires is deterministic real-time response, and that is seldom simply a matter of MHz or MIPS - you will get more deterministic and possibly faster response from an 8bit AVR running at a few MHz than you can guarantee from a 500MHz application processor running Linux - and it won't take 30 seconds to boot!